# Efficiency of operations on R data structures

Tags: r, performance

I'm wondering if there's any documentation about the efficiency of operations in `R`, specifically those related to data manipulation.

For example:

- I imagine it's efficient to add columns to a data frame, because I'm guessing you're just adding an element to a linked list.
- I imagine adding rows is slower because vectors are held in arrays at the `C level` and you have to allocate a new array of length `n+1` and copy all the elements over.

The developers probably don't want to tie themselves to a particular implementation, but it would be nice to have something more solid than guesses to go on.

Also, I know the main `R` performance hint is to use vectored operations whenever possible as opposed to `loops`.

- what about the various flavors of `apply`?
- are those just `hidden loops`?
- what about `matrices` vs. `data frames`?

Comment: For more recent info on R performance, Hadley Wickham's Advanced R has an informative section on [performance](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html) and Jeffrey Horner wrote a couple of awesome posts on [Hash Table Performance in R](http://jeffreyhorner.tumblr.com/post/114524915928/hash-table-performance-in-r-part-i).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Data IO was one of the features i looked into before i committed to learning R. For better or worse, here are my observations and solutions/palliatives on these issues:

**1.** That **R doesn't handle big data** (>2 GB?) To me this is a misnomer. By default, the common data input functions load your data into RAM. Not to be glib, but to me, this is a feature not a bug--anytime my data will fit in my available RAM, that's where i want it. Likewise, one of SQLite's most popular features is the in-memory option--the user has the easy option of loading the entire dB into RAM. If your data won't fit in memory, then R makes it astonishingly easy to persist it, via connections to the common RDBMS systems (RODBC, RSQLite, RMySQL, etc.), via no-frills options like the filehash package, and via systems that current technology/practices (for instance, i can recommend [ff](http://ff.r-forge.r-project.org/)). In other words, the R developers have chosen a sensible (and probably optimal) default, from which it is very easy to opt out.

**2. The performance of read.table** (read.csv, read.delim, et al.), the most common means for getting data into R, can be improved 5x (and often much more in my experience) just by opting out of a few of read.table's default arguments--the ones having the greatest effect on performance are mentioned in the R's Help (?read.table). Briefly, the R Developers tell us that if you provide values for the parameters 'colClasses', 'nrows', 'sep', and 'comment.char' (in particular, pass in '' if you know your file begins with headers or data on line 1), you'll see a significant performance gain. I've found that to be true.

Here are the snippets i use for those parameters:

To get the number of rows in your data file (supply this snippet as an argument to the parameter, 'nrows', in your call to read.table):

```
as.numeric((gsub("[^0-9]+", "", system(paste("wc -l ", file_name, sep=""), intern=T))))
```

To get the classes for each column:

```
function(fname){sapply(read.table(fname, header=T, nrows=5), class)}
```

Note: You can't pass this snippet in as an argument, you have to call it first, then pass in the value returned--in other words, call the function, bind the returned value to a variable, and then pass in the variable as the value to to the parameter 'colClasses' in your call to read.table:

**3. Using Scan**. With only a little more hassle, you can do better than that (optimizing 'read.table') by using 'scan' instead of 'read.table' ('read.table' is actually just a wrapper around 'scan'). Once again, this is very easy to do. I use 'scan' to input each column individually then build my data.frame inside R, i.e., df = data.frame(cbind(col1, col2,....)).

**4. Use R's Containers** for persistence in place of ordinary file formats (e.g., 'txt', 'csv').  R's native data file '.RData' is a binary format that a little smaller than a compressed ('.gz') txt data file. You create them using **save**(, ). You load it back into the R namespace with **load**(). The difference in load times compared with 'read.table' is dramatic. For instance, w/ a 25 MB file (uncompressed size)

```
system.time(read.table("tdata01.txt.gz", sep=","))
=>  user  system elapsed 
    6.173   0.245   **6.450** 

system.time(load("tdata01.RData"))
=> user  system elapsed 
    0.912   0.006   **0.912**
```

**5. Paying attention to data types** can often give you a performance boost and reduce your memory footprint. This point is probably more useful in getting data out of R. The key point to keep in mind here is that by default, numbers in R expressions are interpreted as double-precision floating point, e.g., > typeof(5)  returns "double." Compare the object size of a reasonable-sized array of each and you can see the significance (use object.size()). So coerce to integer when you can.

Finally, the 'apply' family of functions (among others) are not "hidden loops" or loop wrappers. They are loops implemented in C--big difference performance-wise. [edit: AWB has correctly pointed out that while 'sapply', 'tapply', and 'mapply' are implemented in C, 'apply' is simply a wrapper function.

Comment: I would like to correct one statement in doug's (otherwise excellent) post, and point to a nice reference on data I/O speeds.

First, not all 'apply' functions are implemented in C. 'lapply' is implemented in C, as is 'sapply' (which wraps 'lapply'). 'mapply' is also implemented in C. 'apply', however, is simply a nice wrapper for 'for'; the same is true of the functions in the excellent 'plyr' package.

Second, check this entry on the Revolutions blog for more information about IO efficiency: http://blog.revolution-computing.com/2009/12/speedreading-files-revisited.html

Comment: Thanks for the correction AWB--my answer amended to reflect your comments.

Comment: I don't follow your first point: are you saying that R does or does not handle big data?  It certainly does (as you point out), so maybe you're stating this as a common misperception by others?

Answer (score 12):

These things do pop up on the lists, in particular on r-devel.  One fairly well-established nugget is that e.g. `matrix` operations tend to be faster than `data.frame` operations.  Then there are add-on packages that do well -- Matt's [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table) package is pretty fast, and Jeff has gotten [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts) indexing to be quick.

But it "all depends" -- so you are usually best adviced to *profile on your particular code*. `R` has plenty of profiling support, so you should use it.  My [*Intro to HPC with R* tutorials](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/presentations.html) have a number of profiling examples.

Answer (score 6):

I will try to come back and provide more detail.  If you have any question about the efficiency of one operation over another, you would do best to profile your own code (as Dirk suggests).  The `system.time()` function is the easiest way to do this although there are many more advanced utilities (e.g. Rprof, as documented [here](http://wiki.r-project.org/rwiki/doku.php?id=tips:misc:profiling)).

A quick response for the second part of your question:

> What about the various flavors of apply? Are those just hidden loops?

For the most part yes, the apply functions are just loops and can be slower than `for` statements.  Their chief benefit is clearer code.  The main exception that I have found is `lapply` which can be faster because it is coded in C directly.

> And what about matrices vs. data frames?

Matrices are more efficient than data frames because they require less memory for storage.  This is because data frames require additional attribute data.  From [R Introduction](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Data-frames):

> A data frame may for many purposes be regarded as a matrix with columns possibly of differing modes and attributes