# Trying to merge two dataframe based on a specfic column

Tags: r, linux, database, dataframe, dplyr

I have two large dataframes 'a' with no of rows=12056436 and 'b' has 65889001

| chr | pos | A1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24353 | G |

| pos | A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24533 | A | G |

I need an output with all columns chr,pos,A1,A2 but 'pos' values need to be present in both A1 and A2. I am trying to find intersection of both dataframes based on column 'pos' using dplyr package, I tried, innerjoin, semi_join and intersect, But all taking too much time,

```
x <- inner_join(a,b,by='pos')
```

Can some one suggest the best way to do that?

Comment: Take a look at base R's `merge` or at the `data.table` package.

Comment: just tried merge as well but it is taking too long

Comment: Try converting those into matrix. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971323/efficiency-of-operations-on-r-data-structures